# Property of ordinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

i am stuck in proving this Theorm according to my textbook .

> Theorm States that if $\lambda$ is a ordinal numbers and $S(\lambda)$ be the set of ordinals less than ordinal $\lambda$ . Then ordinal of $S(\lambda)$ is equal to $\lambda$

So proof following a very standered way is through finding a similar mapping between $A$ and $S(A)$ where A is well ordered set whose ordinal number is $\lambda$. and the process of proving it is very easy and i understand it.

But i also studied in basic properties of of well ordered set that A set never similar to it's any of the initial sagment and i also prove this result by contradiction.

So how these two well proved Theorms are opposing to each other. Can anyone please help me to finding flaw in my procedure.

Comment: All caps is generally understood to be the internet equivalent of shouting/yelling. Did you mean to be yelling?

Comment: Your theorem doesn't make any sense, and your question is imprecise. This "Theorem" just defines a set.

Comment: Oops sorry , i edit the question. Please see now

Comment: How is "ordinal" defined and how is "less than" defined? The usual definition makes the theorem trivial, since usually $\lambda=S(\lambda)$ by definition.

Comment: In any way, what I suspect might solve your confusion: a well-ordered set $A$ is never similar to any of the *proper* initial segments of $A$, so if $B<A$, then $A$ is never similar to $S(B)$, but naturally $A$ is similar to $S(A)$ itself, since $A$ is not a *proper* initial segment of $A$.